Realization of Conditional Expression
I am trying to use the "Solve" and "Assuming" commands to satisfy a system of equations. Mathematica is able to produce a conditional expression which satisfies the system of equations. The solutions to the system, however, are quite ugly and difficult to parse. I  was wondering if there was a way to use Mathematica to generate a particular assignment of variables to satisfy the conditional expression. Here is the code I am working with:
Assuming[ a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && d > 0 && e > 0 && f > 0   && \[Lambda] > 0 , 
 Solve[-a^2 b^2 + (-1 + b^2 + c^2) (-1 + a^2 + e^2) == 
    0 && -e^2 f^2 + (-1 + a^2 + e^2) (-1 + d^2 + f^2) == 
    0 && -c^2 d^2 + (-1 + b^2 + c^2) (-1 + d^2 + f^2) == 
    0 && -b^2 c^2 + (-1 + a^2 + b^2) (-1 + c^2 + d^2) == 
    0 && -a^2 e^2 + (-1 + a^2 + b^2) (-1 + e^2 + f^2) == 
    0 && -d^2 f^2 + (-1 + c^2 + d^2) (-1 + e^2 + f^2) == 
    0 && (b*d*e) + (a*c*f) == \[Lambda], Reals]]


FindInstance[
 a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && d > 0 && e > 0 && 
  f > 0 && \[Lambda] > 
   0 && -a^2 b^2 + (-1 + b^2 + c^2) (-1 + a^2 + e^2) == 
   0 && -e^2 f^2 + (-1 + a^2 + e^2) (-1 + d^2 + f^2) == 
   0 && -c^2 d^2 + (-1 + b^2 + c^2) (-1 + d^2 + f^2) == 
   0 && -b^2 c^2 + (-1 + a^2 + b^2) (-1 + c^2 + d^2) == 
   0 && -a^2 e^2 + (-1 + a^2 + b^2) (-1 + e^2 + f^2) == 
   0 && -d^2 f^2 + (-1 + c^2 + d^2) (-1 + e^2 + f^2) == 
   0 && (b*d*e) + (a*c*f) == \[Lambda], {a, b, c, d, e, 
  f, \[Lambda]}, Reals]

(* {{a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 1, e -> 1, f -> 1, \[Lambda] -> 2}} *) 


Great this seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Is there any way to produce more possible instances? Thanks.

E.g. FindInstance[ eqs, vars, 10] finds   $10$ solutions.

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear[a, b, c, d, e, f, \[Lambda]]

Use the assumptions to simplify the results
sol1 = Assuming[
  a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && d > 0 && e > 0 && f > 0 && \[Lambda] > 0, 
  Solve[-a^2 b^2 + (-1 + b^2 + c^2) (-1 + a^2 + e^2) == 
      0 && -e^2 f^2 + (-1 + a^2 + e^2) (-1 + d^2 + f^2) == 
      0 && -c^2 d^2 + (-1 + b^2 + c^2) (-1 + d^2 + f^2) == 
      0 && -b^2 c^2 + (-1 + a^2 + b^2) (-1 + c^2 + d^2) == 
      0 && -a^2 e^2 + (-1 + a^2 + b^2) (-1 + e^2 + f^2) == 
      0 && -d^2 f^2 + (-1 + c^2 + d^2) (-1 + e^2 + f^2) == 
      0 && (b*d*e) + (a*c*f) == \[Lambda], Reals] // FullSimplify]


Since you aren't necessarily looking for all the answers, add additional constraints to further simplify.
sol2 = Assuming[
  a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && d > 0 && 0 < e <= 1 && f >= 1 && \[Lambda] > 0, 
  Solve[-a^2 b^2 + (-1 + b^2 + c^2) (-1 + a^2 + e^2) == 
      0 && -e^2 f^2 + (-1 + a^2 + e^2) (-1 + d^2 + f^2) == 
      0 && -c^2 d^2 + (-1 + b^2 + c^2) (-1 + d^2 + f^2) == 
      0 && -b^2 c^2 + (-1 + a^2 + b^2) (-1 + c^2 + d^2) == 
      0 && -a^2 e^2 + (-1 + a^2 + b^2) (-1 + e^2 + f^2) == 
      0 && -d^2 f^2 + (-1 + c^2 + d^2) (-1 + e^2 + f^2) == 
      0 && (b*d*e) + (a*c*f) == \[Lambda], Reals] // FullSimplify]

(* {{a -> Sqrt[1 - ((-1 + d^2) e^2)/(-1 + d^2 + f^2)], 
  b -> (d e f)/Sqrt[(-1 + d^2 + f^2) (-1 + e^2 + f^2)], 
  c -> Sqrt[1 - (d^2 (-1 + e^2))/(-1 + e^2 + f^2)], \[Lambda] -> (
   f (-1 + d^2 + e^2 + f^2))/Sqrt[(-1 + d^2 + f^2) (-1 + e^2 + f^2)]}} *)

You can then assign arbitrary values with d > 0, 0 < e <= 1, f >= 1
sol2 /. {{d -> 1, e -> 1/2, f -> 1}, {d -> 2, e -> 1/4, f -> 3}}

(* {{{a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 2, \[Lambda] -> 5/2}}, {{a -> (3 Sqrt[7])/8, 
   b -> 1/Sqrt[43], c -> 3 Sqrt[7/43], \[Lambda] -> 193/(8 Sqrt[43])}}} *)


Thank you this is very helpful.
